# How to display selected month dates only in date picker with respect to selecting month in another text box?

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have 2 text boxes, one is to choose month and year, and another with dates. My both date pickers are working fine, but what I need is when I select month and year from one text box, my date picker for another text box needs to display selected month's dates only.

**Here is my code:**

```
 <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label>Month</label>
            <div class="input-group date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtMonth">
                <div class="input-group-addon bg-purple">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label>Date From</label>
            <div class="input-group date">
                <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="txtDateFrom">
                <div class="input-group-addon bg-purple">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**My Javascript:**

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
      $('#txtMonth').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: "MM yyyy",
                viewMode: "months",
                minViewMode: "months"
            })
            $('#txtDateFrom').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            })           
        })</script>
```

This is my month selection textbox. If I select Sep 2019 it means, only sep month dates need to display in dates displaying datepicker.

[image]

Or if removing those previous and next icons on date calendar also enough for my requirement.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is get the index of month you clicked and match it with the month of dates calender if both matches you can show that month date specifically OR give the same id to both year month and date month calender and run a for loop if both matches show it otherwise display hidden

Comment: hi Sir, is there any link to refer?

Comment: i'll make it for you wait

Comment: the styling isn't good but you can get the idea https://codepen.io/Naveen-kashyap/pen/dybKXwr

Comment: I checked ur one, in that,date fields are manually created in html, but how to control datepicker that was given by datepicker already

Comment: then you can't change it